# Knitting error: object not found, working directory changed

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When I try to knit my file together I get the error code that says the data file/object is not found. It says I changed the working directory, and it will be restored to a previous directory. The object is in the global environment. Why does the code run but it won't knit>!?

[image: image of the error code]

Comment: The object 'Mosquito' has to be loaded in your RMD file, ist doesn't matter if it's in the global environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code works interactively but not while knitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62563941/code-works-interactively-but-not-while-knitting)