# Code works interactively but not while knitting

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

I have an RMarkdown document with some R code in it. The code works fine when I'm running it interactively in the console. However, when I try to knit the document (using the "knit" button in RStudio), R throws error messages that some objects cannot be found.

Comment: I'm posting this as a duplicate target. This seems to be one of the most common `knitr` issues and I'm not aware of a suitable duplicate target. Feel free to improve!

Comment: Adding the rstudio tag because (for once!) this is a problem specific to the IDE, not the language

Comment: @HongOoi I agree ... but maybe you want to sort this out with Phil. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compile a document (using the "knit" button in RStudio), [knitting takes place in a separate R session](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/compile.html). Therefore, your document must be **self-contained**:

1. Objects from the Global Environment of your interactive sessions are *not* available when knitting. You must create/load all objects from within your document.
2. You must load all packages used from within your document.

Also note that while knitting, your **working directory is changed** to the directory containing your document (by default). Therefore, relative paths (for example, paths to data sets you want to read) might not point to the expected files.